# Is there any way to use SqlTypes with a SqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to write some simple C# code that will select some data from a SQL Server instance, modify the data, and update the changes back to the database.  But I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly how to do this.  Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);Integrated Security=true;Database=master"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Field FROM test", conn);
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "test");

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["test"].Rows)
    {
        dr["Field"] = someFunction((SqlString)dr["Field"]);
    }

    da.Update(ds, "test");
}
```

But this code is giving me the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: specified cast is not valid.
```

So I change the code to use `string` rather than `SqlString`:

```
dr["Field"] = someFunction((string)dr["Field"]);
```

But then I get this error if there are any nulls in my data:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
```

I thought the whole point of the SqlTypes namespace was to provide types that can handle database nulls.  If that is the case, why can't I use them with a SqlDataAdapter?  Hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What happens if you do `dr.GetSqlString(indexOfFieldColumn)`?

Comment: Whups...nevermind, I misread your "dr" as datareader, not datarow.  That won't work.

Comment: @womp: Error 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'GetSqlString'

Comment: I think you're out of luck with the Fill() operation.  Everything I can find on MSDN just says that by default, DataSets are created using .Net framework types.  I think if you want your datatable to have the SqlTypes, you'll have to code it up manually and pass it to the `Fill()` operation, rather than letting `Fill()` create it for you.

Comment: @womp: Even if I manually code a DataTable, I'll still be accessing DataRows from the DataTable and I won't have any way to cast the data to SqlTypes.

Comment: If the datatable had the Field column typed to SqlString, wouldn't the cast  (SqlString)dr["Field"] succeed at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From womp's comment:

If the datatable had the Field column typed to SqlString, wouldn't the cast (SqlString)dr["Field"] succeed at that point? – womp Sep 10 at 17:11

This was the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I could be very wrong here (just a disclaimer), but I think you need to make a new SqlString from your db value, like so:
I think that will work for your null case, I haven't tested it though.

```
    SqlString str = (dr["Field"] == null) ? SqlString.Null : new SqlString((string)dr["Field"]);
someFunction(str);
```

Comment: +1 - this will work.  The bigger question is why can't you get the `DataAdapter.Fill()` function to create a datatable that uses SqlTypes?  There doesn't seem to be any options to do that.

Comment: This didn't work: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: `someFunction(new SqlString((string)dr["Field"]))`

Comment: @womp: That compiles, but it still doesn't handle database nulls properly.  The string cast converts DbNull to an empty string, which is not the same thing on the database.

Comment: You could always check for null before you called someFunction() and make the new SqlString accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the ReturnProviderSpecificTypes property:

```
dataAdapter.ReturnProviderSpecificTypes = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dr["Field"] = someFunction(dr["Field"] is DbNull ? null : (string)dr["Field"]);
```